# What is the lifetime of temporary arguments in nested function calls?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, lifetime, temporary-objects

Consider the program:

```cpp
#include <print>
#include <string>

struct X
{
    std::string tag;

    ~X() { std::println("X::~X() - {}", tag); }
};

X f(const X& x) {
    std::println("f() - {}", x.tag);
    return {x.tag + "!"};
}

int main() {
    f(f({"x"}));
}
```

For a confoming C++(23) compiler, am I correct to assume the following output:

```
f() - x
f() - x!
X::~X() - x!!
X::~X() - x!
X::~X() - x
```

Meaning the lifetime of the temporary objects referenced through function parameters ends **after** running the full expression (1), and the temporaries are destroyed in reverse order of creation (2).

Note that `f()` takes `X` by reference. If it were declared `X f(X x)` instead, then the `X` object may in fact be destroyed as soon as the function returns (3):

```
f() - x
X::~X() - x
f() - x!
X::~X() - x!
X::~X() - x!!
```

I think these are the relevant quotes from the standard:

1. [[class.temporary#6.9]](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#6.9)

> A temporary object bound to a reference parameter in a function call
> ([expr.call]) persists until the completion of the full-expression
> containing the call.

2. [[class.temporary#8]](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#8)

> The destruction of a temporary whose lifetime is not extended beyond
> the full-expression in which it was created is sequenced before the
> destruction of every temporary which is constructed earlier in the
> same full-expression.

3. [[expr.call#6]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.call#6)

> It is implementation-defined whether the lifetime of a parameter ends
> when the function in which it is defined returns or at the end of the
> enclosing full-expression.

Comment: P.S. Before closing as duplicate, please consider the question is more specific than "what is the lifetime of temporary function arguments" and it would benefit from a clear answer.

Comment: "...persists until the completion of the full-expression containing the call." is that not the answer?

Comment: [class.temporary#8] describes the order of destruction. [expr.call#6] isn't necessary, it just explains how the order may change when `X` is passed by value.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/6ndWebqeo basically temporary exist until semicolon.

Comment: Indeed, that's what I expect. But it's difficult to tell for sure because of the numerous exceptions in [class.temporary] and other places. A language lawyer is needed.

Comment: Also note that optimisation under the as-if rule would result in different outcomes given a trivial, non-trivial, or pure destructor.

Comment: Here is your example [pumped up a bit](https://godbolt.org/z/fvvvdoMjT).

Comment: The phrase "It is implementation-defined..." means that the order should not be relied upon for portable code.

Comment: @Eljay There's no implementation-defined behavior except for the hypothetical case where `f()` takes `X` by value.

Comment: Correct.  That is the case of interest.

Comment: Citations 1 and 2 answer the question. What do you need a language lawyer for if you've already found the answer?

Comment: Because the standard wording is so obtuse. My reading: [class.temporary#6.9] is an exception to the lifetime rule in [class.temporary#6] which itself is one of four contexts that don't respect [class.temporary#4]. It's an _exception_ to an _exception_ to the original rule that "temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression".

Comment: Anyway, thanks for confirming. I've added the answer.

Answer (score -2):

> the lifetime of the temporary objects referenced through function parameters ends after running the full expression (1), and the temporaries are destroyed in reverse order of creation (2).

That's correct. According to the C++ standard:

1. [[class.temporary#6.9]](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#6.9)

> A temporary object bound to a reference parameter in a function call
> ([expr.call]) persists until the completion of the full-expression
> containing the call.

2. [[class.temporary#8]](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#8)

> The destruction of a temporary whose lifetime is not extended beyond
> the full-expression in which it was created is sequenced before the
> destruction of every temporary which is constructed earlier in the
> same full-expression.

Comment: This adds nothing to the question. These quotes were already there in the question. Also this doesn't actually explain things. This is basically just copy pasting the quotes from the standard. Looks more like a yes or not question. Additionally there are duplicates that have answer with the same quotes as in this answer. So this should be closed.

Comment: What more is there to explain? It confirms my original assumption by quoting the standard. Is it better to leave the question unanswered and expect the reader to figure it out from comments?